# Codename One: how to get the width in millimeters of a component?

Tags: codenameone

I created an app to calculate the sizes of a multi-image, in order to use them in the Codename One designer.

As you can see in the screenshot below, my app has a slider and I get the width (in millimeters) of it. The problem is that the value of the selected width is incorrect. I tested the app on two Android devices and the measured lengths are different from the ones reported by the app.

You can see the [full source code](https://github.com/jsfan3/CodenameOne-Apps/tree/master/MultiImageCalculator), however the relevant code is the following:

```
Label value = new Label("Move the cursor on the slider...");

Style thumbStyle = new Style();
thumbStyle.setFont(Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_MONOSPACE, Font.STYLE_BOLD, Font.SIZE_LARGE), true);

Slider slider = new Slider();
slider.setMaxValue(1000);
slider.setMinValue(0);
slider.setProgress(20); // Set  the starting value
slider.setThumbImage(FontImage.create("|", thumbStyle));
slider.setEditable(true); // to it works as a slider instead of a progress bar
slider.addActionListener(e -> {
    Integer valueSelected = slider.getProgress();
    Integer sliderWidth = slider.getWidth();
    Double inch = sliderWidth.doubleValue() / (slider.getMaxValue() - slider.getMinValue()) * valueSelected / 100.0;
    Integer millimeters = Double.valueOf(inch * 25.4).intValue();
    value.setText("Value selected: " + millimeters.toString() + " mm");
});
```

Thank you very much for any help

[image: Codename One MultiImage Calculator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Millimeter measures aren't accurate. A device can return different values or ratios for the convert method than the value it returns for the density flag.

Unfortunately, Googles test suite to certify a device as "good" doesn't actually cover these things. There isn't much we can do about that.

Comment: So "Integer sliderWidth = slider.getWidth();" (as in the code above) is inaccurate (and not well documented in my opinion, because the API doesn't report which unit of misure is used in the return value). I didn't get if "Display.getInstance().getDeviceDensity()" is more accurate or not: what is the best way to generate a multi-image of the wanted size?

Comment: `getWidth` is 100% accurate as it works with pixels. Density is a bit of a coin toss. We use getDeviceDensity to pick the right image size. We have some hard coded best practices in the designer tool code that imports multi images you can just look thru the github code for the designer tool

Comment: Density and DPI are the same thing?
My above code is wrong, because I assumed that getWidth() returns a multiple of inches instead of pixels:

            /*
            Double inch = sliderWidth.doubleValue() / (slider.getMaxValue() - slider.getMinValue()) * valueSelected / 100.0;
             */

I tried to fix it so:
[sliderActionListener.java](https://gist.github.com/jsfan3/6ee8358a71a4e79fd7360814f0a78c8c)

I tried to implement MultiImageCalculator.getDeviceDPI() so:
[getDeviceDPI.java](https://gist.github.com/jsfan3/80c915f752a92d4f2f860b717197d6fc)

Is this approch correct?

Comment: We always work with pixels and those are 100% accurate for all cases. This might work for you, it's very much trial and error to get these numbers right